# How can I find the number of segments which are of different colors in a straight line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> In a line segment, $100$ points are marked as indicated in the figure
>   as shown below, which are numbered consecutively, starting at one end,
>   with the numbers from $1$ to $100$. The points which its corresponding
>   numbers are divisible by $3$ are painted red and the rest blue, how
>   many segments whose ends are of different color the most?

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{2275}\\
2.&\textrm{2244}\\
3.&\textrm{2211}\\
4.&\textrm{2040}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly can I find the number of segments?.

Between $1$ and $100$ the number of points which will have multiples of $3$ be:

$\frac{99-3}{3}+1=33$

Then there will be $33$ points which will be divisible by $3$.

But in $100$ points there will be $99$ segments. But I don't know exactly how can this be scaled to any of those alternatives. Can someone help me?.

Comment: The segments include those which overlap, including $2-8, 3-97, 4-7,$ etc. Any pair of points defines a segment.

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay **now** I'm confused. :(

Comment: The segment $3-97$ starts at point $3$ and ends at point $97$.  It includes most of the line segment.  It overlaps with lots of other segments.

Comment: @RossMillikan Gee now I'm getting the idea. But I don't know how to account for those.

Comment: What do you mean account for those?  You are just asked how many segments have differently colored ends.  The fact that they happen to overlap doesn't matter at all.  For example, does $3-97$ have differently colored ends?

Comment: @RossMillikan You mentioned that to make a segment with different colored ends I have to select one red point and one blue point. This I understand. But there are going to be many segments overlaping which do also fulfill this criteria. You mentioned $3-97$ this starts with red and ends with blue as 97 is not divisible by three.

Comment: The fact that the two ends are different colors is all you have to pay attention to.  There are $\frac 12\cdot 100 \cdot 99$ total segments.  For each one, we ask whether the ends are different and count up those that are.  When we ask about one, we ignore all the rest.  We are asked the final count.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why are there a total of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 100 \cdot 99$ total segments?. How did you get to that number. Can you explain this?. The answer is 2211 not 4950?.

Comment: You can choose one end in 100 ways, the second end in 99 ways, but that double counts them. Do you see why? That's why there's the $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @NickD The third end in 98 ways? and so on?. Is this the way how it works?.

Comment: No: a segment has two ends - there is no third end. I should have said "You can choose one end in 100 ways and the other end in 99 ways".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $33$ red points and $67$ blue points.  To make a segment with different colored ends you select one red point and one blue point, which you can do in (how many) ways.

Comment: So would it be $33\times67$, so is $2211$?. Am I right?.

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: Wait!. I'm trying to understand **why**. The way how I'm picturing this mentally is that you can pair those 33 red points with each 67 points hence there are a total of 2211 segments. But what it was mentioned above regarding the *total number of segments* is the part where I'm stuck at.

Comment: Your picture is correct.  $2211$ is the number of segments with opposite colored ends.  I don't see "total number of segments" in the question, but it ends with "the most" which I don't understand.  I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: The source of confusion is the *justification* of *there are a total segments $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 100 \cdot 99$* the **reason** behind this count.

Comment: NickD has it right. You choose two endpoints, which you can do in $100 \choose 2$ ways

Comment: Sorry I had an error in typing. What I meant to say is that I suggest you upgrade your last comment to be part of your answer because that helped me to understand better this problem. But the 4950 are the total ways, among those the only segments which are different are just $2211$ because these only fulfill the criteria of having two different colors? Right?. Btw the binomial you used it doesn't consider repetition and the order, am I right with this?.

Comment: That is correct.  $4950$ is the total number of segments regardless of the color of the ends.  The binomial does not allow repetition and different orders are considered the same, which is where the $\frac 12$ comes from.

Comment: I voice my opinion that your latest comment along the previous one should be added to your answer as an explanatory note because **I really found them helpful** in the solution of this problem. :)